# WPF. Textbox_textchanged not working for the last character, refuses to subtract last integer

Tags: wpf

I´ve got a small issue with my textbox-event...

When entering a number everything works fine and the integer in the textbos is subtracted from my sum that i have as an property in another class, but when I am deleteing the same number the last singular refuses to be subtracted from my variable that is connected to a label. I have to write 0 in the textbox to set the my label to my property.

If someone could helt me out I would be really gretfull!

```
    private void txtBoxDiscount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (inv.TotalAllItems > Int32.Parse(txtBoxDiscount.Text))
            {
                float temp = 0;
                temp = inv.TotalAllItems - Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxDiscount.Text);
                lblTotalAmount.Content = temp;                   
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Discount can not be greater than the total amount.\nPlease try again", "Something went wrong", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Hand);
                txtBoxDiscount.Text = "";
                lblTotalAmount.Content = inv.TotalAllItems;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the empty `catch` block. You'll find that `Int32.Parse(txtBoxDiscount.Text)` throws an exception when `txtBoxDiscount.Text` is an empty string. This is why you should never use an empty catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in the empty `catch` block. You'll find that `Int32.Parse(txtBoxDiscount.Text)` throws an exception when `txtBoxDiscount.Text` is an empty string. This is why you should never use an empty catch block.

Use `Int32.TryParse()` instead. If the text can't be parsed as a number, it will leave `discount` equal to zero.

```
private void txtBoxDiscount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int discount = 0;

    Int32.TryParse(txtBoxDiscount.Text, out discount);

    if (inv.TotalAllItems > discount)
    {
        float temp = 0;
        temp = inv.TotalAllItems - discount;
        lblTotalAmount.Content = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Discount can not be greater than the total amount.\nPlease try again", "Something went wrong", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Hand);
        txtBoxDiscount.Text = "";
        lblTotalAmount.Content = inv.TotalAllItems;
    }
}
```

If you want to treat a non-numeric string as an error, rather than as zero, `Int32.TryParse()` also returns `false` when the parse fails:

```
    private void txtBoxDiscount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int discount = 0;

        if (!Int32.TryParse(txtBoxDiscount.Text, out discount))
        {
            //  Do something else
        }
        else if (inv.TotalAllItems > discount)
        {
```

Comment: @ToniDellAquila Great. You can mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark